# Angular-Cli v1.6.6 Source Map Setup For Microsoft Edge Browser

Tags: angular-cli, microsoft-edge, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to get the correct setup for a Angular-Cli project so that source maps work in Microsoft Edge. 
Angular-Cli v1.6.6
webpack v3.10.0

From the enabling the source map support in the configuration it works in Chrome but not in Edge.  In Edge I see errors like:

> Could not locate webpack:///(webpack)-dev-server/client?32cc specified in source map

And I see "eval code (xxx)" only links.

From what I can google "webpack:///" is not supported in Edge but I have not been able change the Angular-Cli setup to change it to something else (or I don't understand how to).

Just doing the "ng eject" makes the source map from not working to semi working (how maps correctly into the generated bundled js files, but not the unbundled js files like in Chrome) but I still see the "Could not locate webpack:///" like messages in Edge.

I have tried editing webpack.config.js file to change the "devtool" setup and/or the "SourceMapDevToolPlugin" parameter settings.

None of my tests have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My source mapped files works well: have you tried searching along the "no domain" folder of the "debugger" tab? (see my image below, sorry for the italian localization)

[image]

In that folder all your source mapped files will be visible (but i admit that i prefer the chrome way instead of a meaningless "no domain" folder).

P.S. In angular-cli i have used `ng build --prod --source-map`. All my files are minified.

Comment: Yes, the procedure you describe for locating source mapped files works for me too, thanks, so this functionality appears to be working even while Edge is claiming otherwise.  Your preference for Chome DevTools is shared by me, and surely many others, but I needed help with this for debugging Edge-specific issues, thanks.